# How to write a method that will check values into inputted textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

This is a simple question but how would I write a method that will check the inputted values in textboxes and if these values are a specific value then I would store it in a session. For example I have a Username and a password textbox. In my Login button click I have

```
            if
        (txtUsername.Text = "username" && txtPassword.Text = "password")
        {
            User u = new User();
            Session["Login"] = txtUsername.Text;
        }
```

I get a error saying "Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type string and string. How would I fix this?

Comment: this is staring you right in the face.. when doing assignment in C# it's `=` when doing comparison it's `==` sounds like you need to revisit the basics of C# Conditional Statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two values and so use `==` operator instead of `=` operator. `=` operator is for assigning a value (known as assignment operator) and not for comparison.

```
    if (txtUsername.Text == "username" && txtPassword.Text == "password")
    {
        User u = new User();
        Session["Login"] = txtUsername.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For value comparison you need to use double equals:

```
txtUsername.Text == "username"
```